# How can I create unique id based on the value in the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique-id

I wanted to assign the unique id based on the value from the column. For ex. i have a table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]}
```

Eventually I would like to have my output table looks like this:

|  | A | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | 0 | 3 |
| 14 | 0 | 3 |
| 15 | 0 | 3 |
| 16 | 0 | 3 |
| 17 | 0 | 3 |
| 18 | 0 | 3 |
| 19 | 1 | 4 |
| 20 | 1 | 4 |
| 21 | 1 | 4 |
| 22 | 0 | 5 |
| 23 | 0 | 5 |
| 24 | 0 | 5 |
| 25 | 0 | 5 |
| 26 | 1 | 6 |
| 27 | 1 | 6 |
| 28 | 1 | 6 |

I tried `data.groupby(['a'], sort=False).ngroup() + 1` but its not working as what I want. Any help and guidance will be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: if possible - can you please format your expected output and re-post your question again ?

Comment: I rolled back your changes. Please don't post image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diff` + `cumsum`:

```
df['id'] = df.A.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

df
    A  id
0   0   1
1   0   1
2   0   1
3   0   1
4   0   1
5   0   1
6   0   1
7   1   2
8   1   2
9   1   2
10  1   2
11  1   2
12  1   2
13  0   3
14  0   3
15  0   3
16  0   3
17  0   3
18  0   3
19  1   4
20  1   4
21  1   4
22  0   5
23  0   5
24  0   5
25  0   5
26  1   6
27  1   6
28  1   6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdrle
df["id"] = pdrle.get_id(df["A"]) + 1
df
#     A   id
# 0   0   1
# 1   0   1
# 2   0   1
# 3   0   1
# 4   0   1
# 5   0   1
# 6   0   1
# 7   1   2
# 8   1   2
# 9   1   2
# 10  1   2
# 11  1   2
# 12  1   2
# 13  0   3
# 14  0   3
# 15  0   3
# 16  0   3
# 17  0   3
# 18  0   3
# 19  1   4
# 20  1   4
# 21  1   4
# 22  0   5
# 23  0   5
# 24  0   5
# 25  0   5
# 26  1   6
# 27  1   6
# 28  1   6
```